# visualforce page PDF not fitting the screen widht

Tags: visualforce, pdf, rerender

i am rendering a visualforce page as PDF, but if the device is a mobile phone, the pdf is shown only for a small part, and the user needs to scroll to the right.
Is there a way to always show the pdf as full page? Like i am seeing if from the desktop version.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" renderAs="PDF">
              <apex:outputText escape="false" value="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit."  ></apex:outputText>
```

</apex:page>

Current behaviour:
[image]

Expected behaviour but with the mobile ratio as above:

[image]

When i turn the mobile phone everything works ok because there is enough width i guess :
[image]

Comment: This is just the way your phone opens pdfs. You can't adjust that with your code. If you want a responsive design use a website.

Comment: Ok would this be possible with a lighting component that calls the visualforce page as pdf?

Comment: Pdf's are meant for printing documents. They have a fixed layout so that when someone sends it to a printer the printer will know exactly what to print where. That means the publisher of the pdf is assured that it will look good. In  the online world, pdfs are useful if you want to give your user information that they can easily save on their own computer or phone. If you want to give your user an easy to read website then you shouldn't use a pdf or base it on that. You can, if you want to, create a visualforce website that can also be rendered as a pdf but that can be quite the challenge.

Comment: Alternatively, you can build a website and than use javascript to render a pdf in the user's browser.

Comment: Yes my main goal is to display some rich text fields to an user, in my salesforce website. So i can easily add flow,visualforce or components to the page.
The issue is that i want to have the text that changes the font size based on the website screen. This works no problem in a visualforce page with CSS, but it doesn't work with Rich text fields. That's why i opted to have a pdf which is always shown in the save way. I checked this : 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30921225/16859335

Comment: Because when i use the <text> tag everything works, the text is always shown with a size based on the screen, but with the <apex:outputText> tag this doesn't work. And i need to display a rich text field, and this works with <apex:outputText>

Comment: You can make a Visualforce page that renders properly on all form factors. You can't do that with a pdf. The answer you linked to is not actually the accepted answer and from a quick glance I'd say the accepted answer makes more sense. However, if you have little CSS experience you might be better of reading up on that first.